# Are there places in Belgium or netherlands where you can buy coffee green beans for agricultural reasons?

Tags: beans, coffee-culture, home-roasting

I want to grow my own coffee tree from the seed in my home in Belgium but I can't find living coffee beans.

I went to a local coffee enterprise(Miko Turnhout) to ask for unburned seeds (green beans). They told me that their green beans are already neutralized(killed) so they don’t germinate during the transport. I looked online to buy green beans but I only could buy it in large amounts (min. 1kg) and it was very expensive because it had to travel from southern hemisphere.

Are there places in Belgium where you can buy coffee green beans for agricultural reasons? Or are there websites where you can order a small amount of coffee green beans without shipping them from the other side of the world?

Comment: Even if you buy, it will be a real burden to grow Coffee in Belgium (low lands, no mountains, cold weather). I suppose you are aware of that.

Comment: yes, I know but I'm going to grow it indoors and because I start from the seed I don't have to worry about the height just yet.

Comment: It is perfectly possible to grow the plant, but don't expect it to carry any fruits or that you could even use them to make tasty coffee. You can buy the seeds online. In Germany at least, so I suppose it would be the same anywhere in Europe. In stores I never saw them. Some plant stores carry already grown plants, saw it once anyways. Good luck with your endeavor.

Answer (score 1):

For other people from Belgium or the netherlands who were searching for green coffee beans to farm. I found a website where you can buy them.

https://www.onszaden.nl/zoeken?s=koffie